# Re-zipping an MDzip file

Tags: zip, enterprise-architect, magic-draw

A client of mine is going through the process of migrating their Magicdraw models to Enterprise Architect.
Because of some issues in transferring the models we wanted to unzip the mdzip files, change the xmi contents, and then rezip them in order to import them into EA.

But for some reason that doesn't seems to work. Even without changing anything to the contents, just unzipping and rezipping the file and then trying to import it into EA we get "analyzing mdzip file" for a few seconds and then it stops.
I'm suspecting that we are using the wrong zip settings to rezip the file.

Does anyone know which settings we should use to produce a valid mdzip file that can be imported into Enterprise Architect?

I tried asking both NoMagic support as Sparx support, but no answer yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My fault was that I was re-zipping the folder and not the individual files, so the resulting zip file had a different structure.

Something I should have seen a lot sooner of course; a typical case of PEBKAC.

Zipping the individual files worked like a charm.